# Zend Framework - Onde ficam as queries de consulta?

Tags: php, sql, zend, zend-framework-2

Tenho uma aplicação utilizando Zend Framework, na estrutura 
MVC, quero saber aonde são feitas as queries de consulta ao banco, estou um pouco perdido pois nunca trabalhei com Zend. Na minha model eu instancio, por exemplo:

```
class Cursos extends Zend_Db_Table{

    protected $_name = 'cursos';

    }
```

mas a consulta em si:

```
select * from cursos
```

onde fica?

Answer (score 2):

O ideal no padrão MVC é que as suas consultas fiquem dentro da Model, para realizar esta consulta que você citou ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
class Cursos extends Zend_Db_Table{

    protected $_name = 'cursos';

    public function getAllCursos() {
        //SELECT * FROM cursos;
        return $this->fetchAll()->toArray();
    }

}
```

Instancie a model no controlador e chame pela função *getAllCursos*, irá te retornar um array com todos os cursos.

Para realizar consultas mais elaborados, com where, join, group, order e etc... o Zend_Db disponibiliza uma série de funções para ajuda-lo.